# Can I submit apps signed using using wildcard App IDs to the App Store?

Tags: app-store, xcode5, app-id

Can I submit apps signed using provisioning profiles that uses the Xcode Wildcard App ID to the App Store?

Currently I have the Xcode wildcard App ID and a developer provisioning profile for it. Does Xcode 5 manage provisioning profiles now? If then, how do I submit the app?

Comment: wildcard id is ok, non-wildcard only needed for game center, push notifications, in-app purchases. Xcode manages provisioning profiles since v4.something. For more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html